# Nodemailer error when required

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

My resume website is almost done, I'm just finalizing a "Contact me" form that should send me an e-mail with some plain text.

Here's what it looks like in Jade:

```
div.contact-email-box
    form(id='contact-form' action='/' method='post')
        h3 Contact me
        div
            label
                span Name:
                input(placeholder='e.g: Mark' type='text' tabindex='1' required autofocus)
        div
            label
                span Email:
                input(placeholder='e.g: mark@example.com' type='email' tabindex='2' required)
        div
            label
                span Message:
                textarea(tabindex='3' required)
        div
            button(name='Submit' type='submit' id='contact-submit') Send Email
```

And here's where I catch the `POST` in my `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express')
              , app = express()
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
})
```

As you can see it does not do anything, yet I receive the following error:

> /home/kade_c/website/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:31
>               compile: [(...args) => this._convertDataImages(...args)],
>                          ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

That happens only when I `require('nodemailer')` even though it is installed correctly to my `node_modules`.

Is this a known bug? How may I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a node version issue to me.  The spread operator is not valid on earlier versions of Node,, check to make sure you are running a version that supports ES6 features.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js version 6+ is must. Check your Node version with the following command:

node --version

If you are not at least 6+ then you must upgrade.

You may receive another error message instructing you to login to your account. In that case, go to your email inbox and you will see a message from Google with a link to a page for setting up less secure app permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Nodemailer is compatible with Node ***version 6 or above*** (as per https://nodemailer.com/about/#requirements)

So follow these steps to upgrade node:

1* sudo npm cache clean -f

2* sudo npm install -g n

3* sudo n stable

4* sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/**5.4.1**/bin/node /usr/bin/node **(the bold text/version should be the one installed in during above step.)**

ie if 8.1.1 is installed then do sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/**8.1.1**/bin/node /usr/bin/node

node –v (Should show updated version now)