# Nodemailer Error Can't Fix

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, syntax-error, nodemailer

I have a very simple application, just starting to get my hands dirty with nodemailer. When I run the app I get errors in the module itself.

app.js:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://me%40gmail.com:supersecretpw@smtp.gmail.com');


var mailOptions = {
    from:    '"Me" <me@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to:      'him@him.com, her@her.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello dude', // Subject line
    text:    'Test email with text', // plaintext body
    html:    "Testing 1..2..7" // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

And I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Andrew\desktop\messy4\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\mailer\index.js:31
            compile: [(...args) => this._convertDataImages(...args)],
                       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andrew\desktop\messy4\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\nodemailer.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

Really not sure what's happenning here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Node.js version 6+ is required. Check your Node version with the following command:

`node --version`

If you are not at least 6+ then you must upgrade.

You may receive another error message instructing you to login to your account. In that case, go to your email inbox and you will see a message from Google with a link to a page for setting up less secure app permissions.

Comment: Linux users likely have to use the command `nodejs --version` to check their version.

Comment: Awesome, that was the problem. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: To upgrade the nodejs to v8.x:     $ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Answer (score 3):

Simply Add this in your package.json file.

```
"engines": {
    "node": "6.9.4"    // You can use any version
  }
```

This will automatically download the node version you provide. By this way you don't need to upgrade your NodeJS every time in server.

Answer (score 1):

Nodemailer is compatible with Node ***version 6 or above*** (as per https://nodemailer.com/about/#requirements)

So follow these steps to upgrade node:

1* sudo npm cache clean -f

2* sudo npm install -g n

3* sudo n stable

4* sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/**5.4.1**/bin/node /usr/bin/node **(the bold text/version should be the one installed in during above step.)**

ie if 8.1.1 is installed then do sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/**8.1.1**/bin/node /usr/bin/node

node –v (Should show updated version now)

Answered here as well [Nodemailer error when required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029463/nodemailer-error-when-required/45447521#45447521)