# Nodemailer Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I downloaded from `heroku` website and did `npm` install and after running I got

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

Note that I write a code 2 weeks ago but that not work today.

Even I tried to install different version of nodemailer but something happens.....

Any idea why? 
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgvQh.jpg)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045637/nodemailer-error-cant-fix

Answer (score 1):

It's basically because of nodejs version.
Mine was v 4.2.6 which was a bit deprecated and after upgrading it to the latest it works like a charm!

To upgrade nodejs to v8.x:

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `...args` to `args` on line 31

If args is not defined then just try an empty array, `[]`

Comment: I tried to change that but, then it says change it e.g. at line 56 and then again change it on 75 line etc etc.

When I all change then some other error shows up!

I tried to search on google and there was bug with nodemailer, is there any alternative to nodemailer?

Comment: that's not a bug, your code's syntax is just not valid

Comment: I think spread operator is valid, or which part do you mean? This occured on my env after updating nodemailer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a old thread but for someone with the same problem maybe it may help.

In my case, I am working on [c9](https://c9.io/?redirect=0) IDE and every time I open my workspace it changes the node version to use to 4.5.6 which not support some of the ES6 features, using `nvm use 8.2.1` (or the lastest node version you have) everything starts working again.

Check that node version is the one you were using.