# can't send the mail using node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I cannot able to send the mail using nodejs program I used node-mailer and nodemailer smtp transport module.This program worked perfectly lastweek.but suddenly now it is not working .I tried but i cannot able to find the error.can anyone help me .Thankyou.

```html
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: 'sampleprogrammers@gmail.com',
        pass: 'ashbdhbedbudu.'
    }
}));

transporter.sendMail({
    from: "sampleprogrammers@gmail.com",
    subject:" hello ji " ,
    text: "I would like to write dialogue",
    attachments:[
        {
            'filename':'link.txt',
            'path': 'E:/STUDIES/CORE SUBJECTS/link.txt'
        }
    ],
    to: "vikirockz456@gmail.com"
}, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
    console.log("Mail sent successfully");
});
```

SEE THE ERROR BELOW:
[image: Error image]

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: what's the error ? without the code, it will be hard to test

Comment: ok I pasted the error.

Comment: It shows an error like :  compile: [(...args) => this._convertDataImages(...args)],.I pasted the entire error above.

Comment: An error is text. Why post a picture of text? Not only is it more effort on your part, it is more difficult to read and it can't be copy-pasted for example into google...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please go through this question : [Nodemailer Error Can't Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045637/nodemailer-error-cant-fix)
Maybe your version of node changed knowingly or unknowingly. It seems your version of node is not compatible with nodemailer.